# Formatting GridView Columns by DataType

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm working on a small winforms app, I'm more of a web developer so forgive me for any ignorance here.

Basically I have a bunch of gridviews that I'm binding from the code behind like:

```
        var con = new SelectOrdersLineItemByOrder() { ConnectionString = ConStr, fk_OrderID = Id };
        DataSet ds = con.ExecuteDataSet();
        gvVendors.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Currently I am formatting columns as such:

```
        gvVendors.Columns[5].FormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
```

For lack of a better word this is a pain in the butt !!!

Is there a way to hook up an event handler or iterate after the fact and say something like:

```
        foreach (column c in gvVendors)
        {
            if(c is DateTime) { Format Accordingly ... }
            if(c is Decimal) { Format Accordingly ... }
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ...

Comment: You're almost there. Iterate over the columns and there must be some sort of format property on the GridView

Comment: What is the data type of `gvVendors`?

Comment: @DourHighArch thats a GridView

Comment: What namespace; there are at least 4 different classes named "GridView". The iterator of a `System.Windows.Controls.GridView.Columns` is a `System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn` and can never be a `DateTime` or anything else, so I do not understand how what you posted could even compile.

Comment: @DourHighArch System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply write a method of your own like FormatGrid() that does all the formatting for you and you call it after assigning it a datasource. Like

```
     var con = new SelectOrdersLineItemByOrder() { ConnectionString = ConStr, fk_OrderID = Id };
    DataSet ds = con.ExecuteDataSet();
    gvVendors.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    FormatGrid();
```

You can use the following property to setup the formatting.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle.Format
```

No need to loop through the columns. You know the column names and they are not going to change dynamically so just

```
   dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumnName"]
```

should be enough.

Comment: I understand that's basically what I'm currently doing.  I want to be to iterate the columns (as there are allot - in multiple instances) and have a global function that formats based on the column data type rather then the hard coded column name.

Comment: you need to check type of c for comparing then

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna  something like dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumnName"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);